Hamiltonian path in graph where every $u,\ v$ has max $3$ length path.
Given a tree $T = (V, E)$  and a graph $G = (V, F)$ such that $F = \{(u,v)\mid\text{ if the distance from $u$ to $v$ in $T$ is at most $3$}\}$, prove that $G$  contains a Hamiltonian path.
So, my attempt is: let's prove by induction.
Basis:$|V| = 2$. So $T$ has $2$ vertices with one road between them, then by definition of $G$, there is an edge $(u,v)$ belonging to $F$, and $G$ is Hamiltonian.
Assume for every $k<n$ and prove for $n$.*
So $T = (V,E)$ such that $|V| = n$. There is $(n-1)$ edges. Thus exists, $v_i$ belongs to $V$ that is a cut vertex (i.e. $T\{v_i\}$ is a disconnected graph with two components),  each of them has less than $(n-1)$ vertices. so by induction assumption, each component has $G$ with a Hamiltonian path.

Let $G_1$ be the first component with the Hamiltonian path $(v_0,v_1, \ldots, v_{i-1})$.
Let $G_2$ be the second component with the Hamiltonian path $(v_{i+1}, \ldots, v_{n})$.

Since $(v_{i-1},v_i)$ and $(v_i,v_{i+1})$ belong to $T$ with distance less than $3$, thus by definition $(v_{i-1},v_i)$ and $(v_i,v_{i+1})$ exists in $G$, so we found $(v_0,\ldots,v_{i-1},v_i,v_{i+1},\ldots,...,v_n)$ path in $G$, then $G$ is Hamiltonian.

Interesting question! But it is better to edit-in one or more of your ideas - maybe others can build on them!

do you mean that {u,v} is in F if the distance from u to v in T is at most 3?

yes . i will edit

I think this can be proved by induction. Given a tree graph, with one node designated as the root of the tree, and its neighbouring nodes are its children. The statement you want to prove is that you can put the all its nodes in a sequence that starts with the root, ends with a particular child of the root, and the distance between subsequent nodes in the sequence is at most 3. Just split the tree into subtrees, and show you can stitch their paths together.

I see you just added your own proof attempt. Two problems: (1) It is possible that none of the vertices have degree 2, so it may be better to cut away an edge rather than a vertex. (2) You need to show that you can stitch the paths together, so you need to ensure that you have a path (or better, a circuit) that starts/ends at the vertex next to your cut edge. You seem to have just assumed that you can find paths that end at $v_{i-1}$ and $v_{i+1}$ but your induction statement does not guarantee that.
